# Android databinding. How to set layout xml file for generated *Binding class

Tags: java, android, data-binding

Let's assume I have my layout file `myview.xml` which created with databinding in mind. Then android will generate `MyViewBinding` class for me. And in some examples I saw code like this:

```
MyViewBinding mbinding = DataBindingUtils.inflate(inflatter, R.layout.myview, parent, false)
/// using mbinding somehow.
```

However if I don't want to use `DataBindingUtils` and wan't to use `MyViewBinding` directly I'm facing with the problem. `MyViewBinding.inflate` have different signature than `DataBindingUtils.inflate` and **don't** accept layout id (in this example it's `R.layout.myview`) as parameter.

So my question is - if I'm using generated binding class like `MyViewBinding` how could I say it which layout file it should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding class name is generated from the layout file. There is a 1-1 mapping between the layout file and the binding class so when you use `MyViewBinding.inflate`, it `will` use `R.layout.my_view`.

Comment: Thanks, that's obvious ofcourse and shame to me that I don't realize such things. However when I trying to use generated binding to get value - it's fails with the error. I create separate question for this http://stackoverflow.com/q/37883771/1988021