# RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null on ViewAgendaItemBinding.bind() method

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have pretty simple code which should be working according several articles regarding DataBinding but for some reason it's not.

I'm trying to use RecycleView together with Databinding.

```
class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ViewAgendaItemBinding binding;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = ViewAgendaItemBinding.bind(itemView); //this is line where it's throw an error.
    }
}
```

I checked generated version of this `bind` method and it's looks like that:

```
public static ViewAgendaItemBinding bind(android.view.View view, android.databinding.DataBindingComponent bindingComponent) {
        if (!"layout/view_agenda_item_0".equals(view.getTag())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("view tag isn't correct on view:" + view.getTag());
        }
        return new ViewAgendaItemBinding(bindingComponent, view);
    }
```

Which is quite strange. Because I don't have `layout/view_agenda_item_0`. this view should use `layout/view_agenda_item` and I abviously not set any tags. However even if I set those tag for this exact element it's still isn't working.

What should I do to fix this?

P.S. However, If I change this code `ViewAgendaItemBinding.bind(itemView)` into this one `DataBindingUtils.bind(itemView)` it's working. Is it an issue in databinding library?

Answer (score 4):

Data binding re-writes your layouts files during compilation so it will add that tag automatically.

`DataBindingUtils.bind` checks if there is an existing binding on the view and re-uses it. Looks like somewhere else you've initialized data binding on that View. I think we should change `ViewAgendaItemBinding.bind` method to do the same as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly get that. I'm pretty confident that this was the single place I trying to bind data, since it was just a dummy example of using adapter with databinding.

Comment: @yigit Is there an issue on the issue tracker for this? I just ran into this bug while using databinding with a recyclerview. My issue was I tried to bind multiple times to the same layout (because it was recycled) and the `XYZ.bind` method doesn't check for an existing point to bind and instead fails because the initial tag was removed on the first (correct) bind.